# Predefine variale for foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I currently try to draw a tikz pic like in Figure 1. It basically is what I want and I could draw it like that for the whole Sequence, but it is very long. Since it is just the same task over and over again I thought I could just put (at least some) into a foreach loop.

Figure 2 was my first try, but as you can see the distances are not alike and not adjustable with `[node distance=0 mm]`. Also I think it will become intricate once the sequence makes a curve.

So I tried something else (Figure 3). This Idea I prefer, but unfortunately it does not work. I fails because the variable `\j` is not defined when the `\foreach` starts and tries to write a node under the `node[draw,circle,be`low =of \j]`node. -> At least I think that this is the problem. So my question is, is it possibly to define a variable`\j`for the`\foreach` loop so she has a starting point?

Is there another approach that could solve the problem?

**Left** = Figure 1; **middle** = Figure 2; **right** = Figure 3

[image] [image] [image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.5 mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}

\begin{document}

    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0 mm]
        
    %   Sequence = GGUCCCAUK
        
        How it should look like Figure 1
        \node[draw,circle] at (0,0)  (G) {\Large G};
        \node[draw,circle,below=of G] (G) {\Large G};
        \node[draw,circle,below=of G] (U) {\Large U};
        \node[draw,circle,below=of U] (C) {\Large C};
        \node[draw,circle,below=of C] (C) {\Large C};
        \node[draw,circle,below=of C] (C) {\Large C};
        \node[draw,circle,below=of C] (A) {\Large A};
        \node[draw,circle,below left=of A] (U) {\Large U};
        \node[draw,circle,below left=of U] (K) {\Large K};
    
        
    % Foreach part works but do not like distances (not easy adjustable) and will maybe make problems later
    %   \foreach \i\j in {1/G,2/G,3/U,4/C,5/C,6/C,7/A}
    %   {   
    %       \node[draw,circle] at (0,-\i)(\j){\Large\j};
    %
    %   }
    %       \node[draw,circle,below left=of A] (U) {\Large U};
    %       \node[draw,circle,below left=of U] (K) {\Large K};
            
            
    %   Fails because variable \j is unknown in the beginning
    %   starter node
    %   \node[draw,circle] at (0,0)  (G) {\Large G};
    %
    %   \foreach \i\j in {1/G,2/U,3/C,4/C,5/C,6/A}
    %   {
    %       \i
    %   }
    
    % Whole Sequence: GGUCCCAUKGUGPAAU\#GDDAGCACUCPGGABUNUGAAPCCAGCGAU??GAGPPCA”AUCUCGGUGGGACCUCCA
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chains` can be programmed to do pretty much anything in a single chain. You can use the `placed` key and change parameters on the fly. A very blunt implementation, which uses two parameters, the direction `growth dir` and the distance `growth dist`, which get changed using some `\ifnum`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[growth dir/.store in=\tikzgrowthdir,
    growth dist/.store in=\tikzgrowthdist,growth dir=-90,growth dist=0.1]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going {at=(\tikzchainprevious.\tikzgrowthdir),
    shift=(\tikzgrowthdir:\tikzgrowthdist),anchor=180+\tikzgrowthdir},
    nodes={on chain,circle,draw}]
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {G,G,U,C,C,C,A,U,K,G,U,G,P,A,A,U}   
  {\ifnum\numexpr\Y>8\relax 
  \tikzset{growth dir=-135}
  \fi
  \node {\X};}
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many more variations possible.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

With two loops and `chains` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.5 mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm,
  start chain = A going below,
  start chain = B going below left,
     C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.3em, inner sep=2pt}
                       ]
\foreach \i in {G,G,U,C,C,C}
    \node[C, on chain=A] {\i};

    \node[C, on chain=B,
          below left=of A-6]    {A};
\foreach \i in {U,K}
    \node[C, on chain=B]        {\i};

     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Inspired by interesting @Pumuckl answer and considering example from TikZ & PGF manual, page 605 (version 3.1.8b), is possible to draw above image in one loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.5 mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm,
  start chain,
     C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.3em, inner sep=2pt}
                       ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {G,G,U,C,C,C, A,U,K}
{
\ifnum\j<7
    \node[C, on chain=going below] {\i};
\else
    \node[C, on chain=going below left] {\i};
\fi
}
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.