# Adressing a node in a foreach tikz chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-chains

Connecting 2 nodes with each other is easy. I have this one cyan node connected with a round node X.

Now I have a [chain consisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581718/predefine-variale-for-foreach-loop) of circle nodes and I want to connect the magenta node box with for example circle 7 in the chain.

Has anyone an idea how I can address the nodes in the chain?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[growth dir/.store in=\tikzgrowthdir,
    growth dist/.store in=\tikzgrowthdist,growth dir=-90,growth dist=0.1]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going {at=(\tikzchainprevious.\tikzgrowthdir),
    shift=(\tikzgrowthdir:\tikzgrowthdist),anchor=180+\tikzgrowthdir},
    nodes={on chain,circle,draw,draw,minimum size=1cm}]
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}   
  {\ifnum\numexpr\Y>3\relax 
  \tikzset{growth dir=-135}
  \fi
  \ifnum\numexpr\Y>5\relax 
  \tikzset{growth dir=-90}
  \fi
   \ifnum\numexpr\Y>10\relax 
  \tikzset{growth dir=-135}
  \fi
  \node {\X};}
 \end{scope} 

% node connection
\node(A) [draw=cyan!20,fill=cyan!20,text width=3cm, rounded corners] at (-4,0) {Description};
\node(X) [draw,circle] at (-2,-2) {X};
\draw[color=cyan!20, line width=1mm] (A.south) |-  (X.west);

\node(A) [draw=magenta!20,fill=magenta!20,text width=3cm, rounded corners] at (-4,-3) {Description};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: first I have given a name to each node in the foreach statement by adding `\node (n\X){\X};}` -- this will give each node a name n1, n2 and so on -- next  is simply add the line of code  `\draw[color=red!70, line width=1mm] (A.south) |-  (n7.west);` which will connect the two nodes -- have look at the answer below

Comment: huh ... are these two lines everything you changed. When I copy these codes snipets into my original file it does not work. Says n7 is unknown. When I copy my nodes into the code you post as answer it works and does what I want. So I assume my original code is maybe missing something else. But anyway I might just use the posted code. thanks

Comment: Ok I think I found the difference in my original document it says `\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14}` instead of `\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}`. So I can´t name my nodes with a 0 in front. I try to live with that

Comment: you can name your nodes as `n0\X` -- this should give n01 n02 so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[growth dir/.store in=\tikzgrowthdir,
        growth dist/.store in=\tikzgrowthdist,growth dir=-90,growth dist=0.1]
        \begin{scope}[start chain=going {at=(\tikzchainprevious.\tikzgrowthdir),
                shift=(\tikzgrowthdir:\tikzgrowthdist),anchor=180+\tikzgrowthdir},
            nodes={on chain,circle,draw,draw,minimum size=1cm}]
            \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}   
            {\ifnum\numexpr\Y>3\relax 
                \tikzset{growth dir=-135}
                \fi
                \ifnum\numexpr\Y>5\relax 
                \tikzset{growth dir=-90}
                \fi
                \ifnum\numexpr\Y>10\relax 
                \tikzset{growth dir=-135}
                \fi
                \node (n\X){\X};}
        \end{scope} 
        
        % node connection
        \node(A) [draw=cyan!20,fill=cyan!20,text width=3cm, rounded corners] at (-4,0) {Description};
        \node(X) [draw,circle] at (-2,-2) {X};
        \draw[color=cyan!20, line width=1mm] (A.south) |-  (X.west);
        
        \node(A) [draw=magenta!20,fill=magenta!20,text width=3cm, rounded corners] at (-4,-3) {Description};
        
        \draw[color=red!70, line width=1mm] (A.south) |-  (n7.west);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```